# In lightning chart js how to disable marker in Y-axis

Tags: lightningchart

I am using this function this.chart.addChartMarkerXY, marker is showing for both x and y axis.
i want to disable for y-axis need help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpKyX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

See [ChartMarkerXY.setTickMarkerYVisibility](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.0.1/classes/chartmarkerxy.html#settickmarkeryvisibility)